# Can't get any account info, or review info

Tags: google-my-business-api

I've tried for hours now to figure this out but I'm completely stuck.

I have been approved for My Business APi and I created a service account and downloaded the json file for authentication.

I am using [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) and with [google-api-my-business-php-client](https://github.com/Avtonom/google-api-my-business-php-client/) which provides the 'Google_Service_MyBusiness' class for use.

My code looks like this: -

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-my-business-php-client/MyBusiness.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.__DIR__.'/myfile.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

if (getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')) {
  // use the application default credentials
  $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
} else {
  echo missingServiceAccountDetailsWarning();
  return;
}

$client->setApplicationName("my_app");
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage');

$service = new Google_Service_MyBusiness($client);
$accounts = $service->accounts;
$accountsList = $accounts->listAccounts()->getAccounts();
```

But all that I ever get back is

```
Google_Service_Exception: That’s an error. The requested URL <code>/v3/accounts</code> was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

I notice that the documentation is now v4, i.e. v4/accounts, could this be the issue? Are these libraries out of date? How can I retrieve account and review data with v3?

Any help would be appreciated.

My end goal is the retrieve all the reviews for a location but right now just trying to get this to work as a prelude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question - I think the main issue is it turns out that My Business api doesn't support service accounts, you need to use oauth2.

Turns out that V3 is depreciated also so the libray I was using for MyBusiness API is useless, the other one works fine for updating access tokens.

For the reviews I am just using Curl and Simply building the URL with the ?access-token= value on the end of it.

For example to list all reviews

https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/[acc-number]/locations/[location-id]/reviews?access_token=

Comment: I've been stuck on this for ages now, simply trying to find the accountID (or account_number as you mentioned above) has proven to be an impossible task. Where can I get this?

Comment: Here is the Drupal module I created for this work, have a look in the .module file -> https://github.com/joehuggans/Drupal-7-Google-MyBusiness-API I'm sorry this was a long time ago I can't remember what I did here.